# Does an electric field induce current in a floating ideal capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

The company "Fluke" makes a DMM that they claim can measure AC voltage by simply clamping the connector around a live wire, and using the E-field to induce a voltage/current into the capacitor.

I can understand the concept if we assume the person holding the DMM is grounded and the measuring loop is sufficiently sensitive. But what if the person holding the DMM is not grounded, or is in a vacuum, etc. Some people on the internet claim it works even if the DMM is hanging from the wire in open air. I have my doubts... So, I am wondering if someone can explain to me if current can flow in a capacitor that has no path to ground. It seems like an obvious "no."